# Upgrade linux package without re-starting it

Tags: linux, apt

Yesterday I found that a new feature in a package (Prometheus) was valuable for me. I was running version 2.24 and the latest available version was 2.35. I then proceeded with `apt-get install prometheus=2.33.5+ds1-2~bpo11+1`. The package got upgraded with no issues.

My problem was that when I first installed version 2.24, the default configuration had a data retention of 1 month and I changed that to 1 year. After upgrading to 2.35, the package installed its default configuration, and it went back to 1 month. As a consequence, when the package was automatically started, all my data older than 1 month was erased. No problem, I had a backup.

In the future, to avoid this situation, is it possible to upgrade a package without automatically starting it? So I have a chance to go and change its default configuration and only then start the package?

Would you advise a different approach to proceed with a package upgrade?

Comment: https://www.faqforge.com/linux/fixed-ubuntu-apt-get-upgrade-auto-restart-services/

Comment: Thanks @ArtemS.Tashkinov. I am currently not running Ubuntu, but Armbian based on Debian. Would you suggest the right approach is to install needrestart?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1421221 this will work for debian too